# multicols not splitting a long list into columns

Tags: lists, enumerate, itemize

I have an enumerated list where each list item has an itemized sublist which I want to be displayed in 3 columns.  Based on other questions/answers I decided the best way was to use the `multicol` package.

This works fine if the sub-list is small, 3 or fewer items, but if the list is longer than the number of columns I specify in the `multicol`s tag, the list comes out as a single item list.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Programming Languages:
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item awk
                \item bash
                \item C 
                \item C++
                \item java
                \item perl
                \item python
            \end{itemize}
        \end{multicols}
    \item Operating Systems:
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Linux
                \item Windows
            \end{itemize}
        \end{multicols}
    \item Network Tools:
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I expect the output to look like this:

```
1. Programming Languages:
awk  bash  c
c++  java  perl
python
2. Operating Systems:
Linux  Windows
3. Network tools
```

With the columns aligned properly.

It may just be how my screenreader is reading the resulting pdf, but I see the list of languages in a single column and the operating systems beside each other.

Comment: I added a screen shot of the output of your code.

Comment: I do not understand your problem though ... what is wrong with the output?

Comment: how you imagine that result should be?

Comment: @Zarko Same idea/question here ;)

Comment: Maybe it is my screenreader's problem, but I picture the result to look something like:

Comment: @dnraikes: The `itemize` environment works vertical, not horizontal ... and I see evil content there: `Java` and `Windows` ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by "screen reader"? Is it a PDF Viewer like Adobe Acrobat or Sumatra PDF?

Comment: No I am blind and a screenreader is what I use to access the computer it is software tht translate what is displayed on the screen into spoken output or braille output depending.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `itemize` environment is working vertically, not horizontally. Either reorder the `\item` statements (*tedious*) or use a better method, say `tasks` package, defining a `\NewTasks` environment and giving it the `style=itemize` option

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tasks}

\NewTasks[style=itemize]{ComputerScience}

\setlist[enumerate,1]{wide=0pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item Programming Languages:
      \begin{ComputerScience}(3)
      \task awk
      \task bash
      \task C 
      \task C++
      \task java
      \task perl
      \task python
    \end{ComputerScience}
    \item Operating Systems:
       \begin{ComputerScience}(2)
        \task Linux
        \task Windows
      \end{ComputerScience}
    \item Network Tools:
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

For a more basic approach, just use `tasks` and `label=\textbullet`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Programming Languages:
      \begin{tasks}[label=\textbullet](3)
      \task awk
                \task bash
                \task C 
                \task C++
                \task java
                \task perl
                \task python
         \end{tasks}
    \item Operating Systems:
        \begin{tasks}[label=\textbullet](2)
                \task Linux
                \task Windows
        \end{tasks}
    \item Network Tools:
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Both show

[image]

Comment: @dnraikes: Happy TeXing then!

Comment: I would improve the layout loading `enumitem` and setting `[wide=0pt]` for `enumerate`.

Comment: @Bernard: That's not a dramatic improvement in my point of view

Comment: It doesn't make it the layout of the century, but it looks nicer for me, especially if there ordinary text around.

Comment: @Bernard: Sigh... I've added your propositions, but I will change the screen shot only later on...